# postgres find zip codes near specific zip code

Tags: sql, postgresql, matching, zipcode

Assuming a Postgres Table containing `zip` as `varchar(10)` I want to get either all results matching a specific zip or extend my results with entries close to the queried one in case there are not enough results. Say:

A user searches for `zip` "56500" and my result-set returns 2 items running an exact match. In this case I want to perform a kind of `like` query that finds "565%" entries. Eventually I need to run this in one query.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might be what you want:

```
SELECT …
FROM atable
WHERE zip = @zip

UNION ALL

SELECT …
FROM atable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM atable
  WHERE zip = @zip
)
  AND zip LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(@zip, 3), '%')
```

This may not be the most efficient solution, but at least it is a single query so might do well as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` the delta from the desired `zip`?

Comment: @HannesMaack, actually, it still comes down to ordering by distance starting with 0. The question is only *how* you calculate this "distance".

Answer (score 0):

So, this is not specifically for PostgreSQL -- it was actually written for MySQL originally -- but it should work.  I came across this article a while back that showed how to create a database containing zipcodes and latitude/longitude for each zipcode, then using trigonometry to calculate the distance between zip codes.  Take a look at the link.  I'm sure it will help you...

http://www.chrissibert.com/blog/2009/06/16/mysql-zip-codes-latitude-longitude-distance/

Comment: Hey Shadowman, I´m not sure if I really need  tables containing latitude/longitude, but I it´s a good solution for my problem ... thx

Comment: If you're looking to calculate distances between zip codes then it's the best way.  If all you're looking to do is get zip codes that are "similar" to the one you're searching for, then it may be overkill.

Comment: The link, above, is now broken. Here's one possible alternative, though: [Implementing Zip Code Proximity Functions in MySQL and PostgreSQL](http://iamtgc.com/implementing-zip-code-proximity-functions-in-mysql-and-postgresql/)