# Rails, all zipcodes within distance from zipcode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, zipcode

I'm trying to find out: given a zipcode, what are all the zipcodes within an X-mile radius of that zipcode.

---

I've found a few solutions, which I've posted below, but I want to know if there are any better solutions specifically for Rails or Ruby (in other words, a gem, a gist, etc.). The Ruby solutions I've found are a few years old, so it seems like there could be a better solution available now.

Ideally I'd want something that just takes a string "11026" and produces strings as output, without me having to create AR models or deal with the database too extensively.

[Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) doesn't seem to do this explicitly... neither does [Geokit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/). I don't know if there's a simple work-around for either of these gems.

---

Similar solutions:

[Find all Zipcodes within specified distance of a zipcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762248/find-all-zipcodes-within-specified-distance-of-a-zipcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql-wise, someone already asked that similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343673/postgres-find-zip-codes-near-specific-zip-code). Kinda simple to implement and would give you good enough results to test your spec.

Otherwise, if you can find a library that has lat/long for each zip, it'd be easy to look at it from a geo-proximity point of view. Then, you should look for Postgresql proximity search.
Find more: http://www.boutell.com/zipcodes/ and http://www.geopostcodes.com/

Comment: The problem with the first link is that it doesn't really use any sort of database, it just matches with the first characters of the zip... which isn't too great of a matcher. Also the other links just seem to be databases of zipcodes?

Comment: I'm looking for something that returns zipcodes closest to a certain zip code. Hopefully something that won't rely on external services (like Geocoder does). Perhaps if zips were stored in a DB with lat/long, and then there was some way to see all zipcodes with nearby lat/longs.

Comment: Free Zip Code Latitude and Longitude Database, having the zip code, you get the coordinates. Having the coordinates, you do geo proximity. Having geo points in the same radius, you make it return the object's zip code. I think you got the gist of it in your second comment. http://www.boutell.com/zipcodes/ seems to be the DB you want. I'd give it a shot.

Comment: Alright, seems good. I think I skipped over the part about PG proximity search when reading your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This API makes it really simple - http://www.zipcodeapi.com/API#radiusSql.  The format is

```
http://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/<api_key>/radius.<format>/<zip_code>/<distance>/<units>
```

Comment: Only 10 requests per hour the free version